# Flow Decision Element Contains Value, executing Default outcome anyway

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a flow where I am looping through related detail records and adding their names to a flow variable "Product Name" - data type text, then adding that variable to variable collection "AllProductNames" - data type text. [image]

[image]

Then I'm using a decision element to see if that variable collection contains a value. However, even though the value is in the variable collection, the default outcome is executed anyway. [image][image]

Comment: The [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_operators_condition.htm&type=5) explains why: "returns true if: An item in the collection that’s selected for Resource contains the exact same value as Value". I.e. it does not find a partial match, only an exact match.

Comment: @PhilW Thank you! That was exactly it. I appreciate it!

Comment: @Hailey mark the question as answered if that's it :)

Answer (score 1):

Not an actual solution to your goal, but the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_operators_condition.htm&type=5) explains why you get the behaviour you see:

> true if: An item in the collection that’s selected for Resource contains the exact same value as Value

I.e. it does not find a partial match, only an exact match.